# 'default object' to initialize nested objects on typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I have the following object on typescript to control results of a sports game:

```js
export interface IResult {
    [day: string]: IResultDay;
}

interface IResultDay {
    [matchId: string]: IMatch;
}

interface IMatch {
    teams: ITeam[];
    winner: ITeam;
    winnerScore: number;
    looserScore: number;
}
```

I build it this way because it allow me to filter the matches I want to see per "day" and per "matchId".

The problem is that when I want to build this object, I need to keep verifying if its not `undefined` on each level. If I don't do that, the following happens:

```js
const result: IResult = {}; // init the first level
result['2020-09-30']['2020093012344321'] = {
  teams: [
    {
      teamId: '1234',
      teamName: 'Lakers'
    },
    {
      teamId: '4321',
      teamName: 'Miami Heat'
    }
  ],
  winner: {
    teamId: '1234',
    teamName: 'Lakers'
  },
  winnerScore: 117,
  looserScore: 107
};
```

The error:

```bash
TypeError: Cannot set property '2020093012344321' of undefined
```

And it get's worse when I go deep on the nested object. Is there a way to build this object without initializing each level?

In python there's this trick on dictionaries that allow us to start multiple levels at the same time:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
my_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))
```

I want something that does exactly the same thing (or something with the same behavior). It's really weird keep initializing each level before creating the object in did.

Is there something like that on javascript/typescript?

Comment: A minor point, which doesn't answer your question. It's `winner` and `loser`, not `looser`. A common mistake. Hopefully you're not too far along to be able to fix it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built in, but you can use a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to intercept the property accesses and insert a default value when a property doesn't exist.  Maybe something like this:

```
function defaultDict<T>(cb: (k: PropertyKey) => T): { [k: string]: T } {
    return new Proxy({} as any, {
        get(target, p, receiver) {
            if (!(p in target)) {
                target[p] = cb(p);
            }
            return target[p];
        }
    })
}
```

I don't know if the callback cares about the key passed in, but it doesn't really matter either way.  Then you can make `result` like this:

```
const result: IResult = defaultDict(() => ({}));
```

which really only needs to have a single `defaultDict()` since to set `result[day][match] = ...` you really only need `result[day]` to be defined.  And then this behaves as you expect, I think:

```
result['2020-09-30']['2020093012344321'] = {
    teams: [
        {
            teamId: '1234',
            teamName: 'Lakers'
        },
        {
            teamId: '4321',
            teamName: 'Miami Heat'
        }
    ],
    winner: {
        teamId: '1234',
        teamName: 'Lakers'
    },
    winnerScore: 117,
    loserScore: 107
};
```

That gives no error, and then this works:

```
for (let day in result) {
    for (let match in result[day]) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result[day][match]))
    }
}
/* {"teams":[{"teamId":"1234","teamName":"Lakers"},{"teamId":"4321","teamName":"Miami Heat"}],
 "winner":{"teamId":"1234","teamName":"Lakers"},"winnerScore":117,"loserScore":107} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICUIGcCuAbMZAbwChlzkBtAEzgE8AuZLMKUAcwF0mNt8wAIvQDcJAL4kSoSLEQpeuAkLrEyFSgFs4YBAAtU1JizYguPALLa9oiVPDR4SNJZ27VFZJDgasPACoQ3pScoh4A7qAg0P6BGqEUESBRUADKCAD2UBBMIDgaAEbQ8eR46VjQaZnZyLkFReKS0g5yaAHe7hReGgZGrBzFnrEAct7Vxv0NJDA4IAhgwOkgyNQQ8PwCwHMAPH4AfAAUCPlM+wDWTAAKUOkADtBgdADSEHQAlMgAvLvIfq9MRFRzsw+qZuD9kGIOuQsmAcFAllEwsgrukAB50fZESFwLDIOAgOgAGihHmQ7AgYH2YDgUHJYGJN2JWSQwAAbtB3qRSdzkMAYMh9gBCfY3XlLam0imvTlqHk8iV0yg3TifZBHEWvAZyiRyjwwuHimmK5Vaig6s2vSYZEAsZBZRRgHiYB2qlZrJSbSn7d5fAVY6WiEj2-iUADkACYAAxRgC0kYAnDGAMyR0OcMNRqMJlMARnDSYALAWk+Gc2nVVzOrFfFRZaTK7rBt4eshQ3nC6HCXW5V0RhpqqGADJwU7QLCh7tmrtyhu6rot0PF0udyfc3ujJih8zAbzAZAACUCYAn2rrnGnCUi0RJHnnhlb7YLK57ww3reHo6g47rYgv5ESySVFkTA5jmADsf7IKU5SpBkwHIDmkZgeIgYwJkAp4BSyz0GKdp8AQMoeGhUAYVhWiuLhwYEDQ9CcIRPLWlg6SYQAdKU7D7AAUikADyQwseMph8hiVFgDRdDpuReh0ZaHgSBIAD0ABUxAAERdFgqkMJQRDqbEBhaapj6qYSeneH2ECGR+Y6qb+ul3oZS45iZZkaBZhnbruB5HrZ55kKpAHQFp9n6dQhnGaZ679lZI42b+AVXrBVRaaBEGqdBFRwZZDCIWBkJKQpQA)

Comment: I guess this is what I'm looking for! I'll check it out. Awesome, thanks

Comment: Have you had a chance to see if this meets your needs?

Comment: does this work if i want one more level nested? Like 3 or 4?

Comment: It's almost perfect. I was wonder if I can do `result['2020-09-30']['2020093012344321'].teams.push({team})`. It still gives me the error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'teams' of undefined`. I know it's harder because the list must be initialized too, but this error is not even releated to the `.push()` method

Comment: I also tried to do that with just **one level** (instead of **two** on first example) to another use case and I got this type error: `Type '{ [k: string]: {}; }' is not assignable to type 'MyNewType'.
  Index signatures are incompatible  Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'MyNewType': prop1, prop2`

Comment: If you want to do `result[d][m].teams.push(team)` then you need a way to create a *default* `IMatch`. This would be easy if the `winner`, `winnerScore`, and `loserScore` properties were *optional*, but they're not.  If they were optional then you could just do `const result: IResult = defaultDict(() => defaultDict(() => ({ teams: [] })));` Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/oN5OMW). Since they're not optional you need to figure it out. I don't know what `MyNewType` is either but I suspect you have the same issue: you need to initialize a default value.

Comment: Anyway this kind of feels like scope creep with respect to the original question.  If this answer helped you then consider voting it up or accepting it.  If you are still having trouble then you might want to either edit the question to include a [mcve] that demonstrates the particular issue you're trying to solve, or ask a new question about the new issues.  Good luck!

Comment: For now I'll just upvote and then try to improve my question to consider thos other scenarios I described. If you could improve the answer then too would be awesome! Thanks a lot for helping. If we can't go any further I'll accept that

Comment: I just started those `winnerScore` and `loserScore` with `0` and `winner` with `undefined`. So it goes like `const result: IResult = defaultDict(() => defaultDict(() => ({ teams: [], winner: undefined, loserScore: 0, winnerScore: 0 })));` will I have some problem following this approach?

Comment: You should change the `IMatch` definition so its `winner` property is optional if you want to initialize it to `undefined`.  And whenever you read the `winner` property of an `IMatch` you'll have to check for it being `undefined` before you use its properties.  Is that okay with you?  Assuming you change `IMatch` to allow for the value you're initializing, I'm tempted to say "no" to "will I have some problem", but of course I don't know everything you're trying to do with `defaultDict` so I can't predict what hypothetical problems you might encounter.

Comment: This is ok for me because I'm populating this object with a database that I'm 100% sure that I will always have a winner defined. I'll accept your answer. Again, thanks a lot, this is exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no, javascript doesn't really have anything to allow setting multiple nested levels of a dictionary all in one go.

Comment: Oh.. That's really sad :(

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript sadly can't do this. However you can achieve this using some dependencies such as `lodash`:

```js
const _ = require('lodash');

const result: IResult = {};
_.set(result, ['2020-09-30', '2020093012344321'], {} /* replace {} with your value */);
```